# Sefardic Boy Dorming on Chanukah 

Tags: chanuka, halacha, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, time-zone

A boy of Sefardic descent who is in the Dorm of a Yeshiva, does he light himself or does he rely on his parents lighting?

Is there a machlokes among the Sefardic Poskim themselves of what to do?

*If they rely on parents then*:

Does any one have a real experience with this question and what did they or the Sefardic student involve do ( I have a feeling they would light without a Bracha just not to seem like an outcast,at least if they where in Ashkenazi Yeshiva)?

Do different time Zones student in America versus parents in Israel or vice versa make a difference??

Comment: You can answer single aspects of the questions too.

Answer (score 4):

The Yalkut Yosef deals with this question, in conclusion the boy rely on the parents, the time zone difference is not a problem

if you want to be mahmir you could give a pruta to a ashkenazi roomate

Comment: My brother asked Rav Yitzhak Yosef in person and he told him to light. Then my brother asked me to ask R' Mansour, but that was unnecessary. In conclusion I told him to light with a Beracha just like R' Yitzhak had said.

Comment: that may be on the specific case of the boy, there are some exceptions, for example if your parents don't light candles

Comment: Our parents like candles. The Yalkut Yosef says even people at home who want to light, he says "en maznihim oto- we don't condemn him." Meaning Kal WaHomer in Yeshiva.

Comment: Today a friend of mine said he heard that the rav ovadia hazar bo on this issue, he heard from another friend in the name of rav david, I still need to find out if this is true or not. If someone heard of this and could confirm or deny would be great

Comment: Yes please, give us prutos. :)

Comment: @Avraham: Rav Ovadia himself writes that you should not believe when someone privately says that a well-published posek retracted his psak. If he wanted to retract his psak, he would have published the retraction.